# issues using an image src in php echo

Tags: php, image, html, echo, src

im having trouble using an image search within php tags, is it possible?
My code bellow:

```
<?php
 echo "<div id=reviewname>Name: ".$dname['name']."</div>";
 echo "<div id=reviewseat>Seat: ".$dseat['seat']."</div>";
 echo "<div id=srating>Sound: ".$dsrating['s_rating']."</div>";
 echo "<div id=crating>Comfort: ".$dcrating['c_rating']."</div>";
 echo "<div id=vrating>View: ".$dvrating['v_rating']."</div><br /><br/>";
 echo "<div id=reviewcomment> Comments: ".$dcomment['comment']."</div>";
?>
```

I would like within these div's to be an image src example being:

```
echo "<div id=srating><img src="images/soundimg.png" alt="Sound" height="35" width="35"></div>Sound: ".$dsrating['s_rating']."</div>";
```

The above does not work, is it a syntactical issue?

Thanks

Comment: The syntax highlighter clearly shows your error. It's a quote issue. You really should be using a text-editor or IDE that offers syntax highlighting. This really is a trivial error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes inside the `echo` statement

```
echo "<div id=srating><img src=\"images/soundimg.png\" alt=\"Sound\" height=\"35\" width=\"35\"></div>Sound: ".$dsrating['s_rating']."</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If not escaping, you can also use `single quotes` for `attribute values`.

```
echo "<div id=srating><img src='images/soundimg.png' alt='Sound' height='35' width='35'></div>Sound: ".$dsrating['s_rating']."</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to echo and in string u need to put `"` quotes, you can use single quote around ur string.

```
echo '<div id=srating><img src="images/soundimg.png" alt="Sound" height="35" width="35"></div>Sound: '.$dsrating['s_rating'].'</div>';
```

same for single quote.
But if you need both single & double quotes you can use any method and use `\'` or `\"`

Or you can have a very useful too, [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.